# forward local port with plink in background and executing command on local machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, putty

I want to write a batch script which forwards a local port on my machine to the server, dataexchange. I have given the server my public key for authentication, and I want to connect using plink, PuTTY's command line SSH tool.

Here's what I want the script to do.

1. Forward the local port 3309 to `dataexchange:3306`.
2. Run a Java program on my local machine which queries the mysql database on `dataexchange:3306`.
3. Closes the port.

I'm a novice at writing in batch, but here is what I think should work. I am not sure how to run the Java program in batch on my machine, and I am not sure how to close plink after it run.

```
@ECHO OFF
plink -L 3309:dataexchange:3306 -l myUser -N &
java -jar myprog.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things backward in your example:

- Your probably want the java program to connect to localhost:3306 which is then forwarded to the remote dataexchange:3306
- The Port forwarding syntax is then: `-L 3306:localhost:3306`
- You need a host to connect to in your plink command. In this case probably myuser@dataexchange
- There is no `&` thing in windows, the `start` command should help you ([Doc](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm))
- After the java program completes you can then use `taskkill /im plink.exe` to kill the plink tunnel. (But beware, that kills all plink processes currently running)
- The java command is probably also wrong, you can't run `.java` files without compilation. (Did you write the program yourself? Then compile it first with `javac`)